# Python returning unbalanced parentheses error when compiling regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to validate geographic coordinates using regular expressions in Python. I have a complex regex that tests for decimal degree coordinates (e.g. 10.4, -23.7 ; N10.4, W23.7 ; etc.) 
I have tested the expression in an online regex tester (https://pythex.org/) and it seems to validate and test my strings properly. When I go to my python code I get an unbalanced parenthesis error when I try to compile the expression. I've counted the open and close parentheses in my expression and they match up. Furthermore I am not searching any parenthesis literals so no escapes in the expression.
the experession I am checking against is:

```
^((?P<firstPrefix>[EeWw\+-])?(?P<longitude>[0]?\d?\d([,.:]\d*)?|1[0-7]\d([,.:]\d*)?|180([,.:]0*)?)([°˚º^~*]*)(?P<firstSuffix>[EeWw\+-])?)([,:;\s|\/\\]+)((?P<lastPrefix>[NnSs\+-])?(?P<latitude>[0-8]?\d?\d([,.:]\d*)?|90([,.:]0*)?)([°˚º^~*]*)(?P<lastSuffix>[NnSs\+-])?)$
```

Can anyone tell me if there is some other reason other than escaped literals that python would not compile my regex?

Comment: which version of Python are you using? If it's Python 2 then encoding seems like the most likely issue

Comment: You need to use a raw string (`r"..."`), otherwise some of the escapes will be interpreted wrongly.

Comment: The culprit is ``\\`` inside `[,:;\s|\/\\]+`. In a regular string literal, it turns into ``\`` and escapes the `]` that stops being the closing `]` for a character class.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. Turns out it was a simple answer. Using a raw string for the regex solved the problem.